# Post a Report in a Sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I have been working in project that create a folder through Business Central when you click on an Action. It's working fine, but now I wanted to when I click in the Action it send the Report, in Page Item Card(30), to my folder in the Sharepoint. I created a procedure to do that, but the problem its when I try to open the Report(PDF) on Sharepoint, it says "looks like the file don't have a preview we can show you."
Here is the procedure that Im using.

```
 procedure UploadFile(AccessToken: Text; Url: Text; Item: Record Item): Boolean
    var
        Client: HttpClient;
        Headers: HttpHeaders;
        RequestMessage: HttpRequestMessage;
        ResponseMessage: HttpResponseMessage;
        RequestContent: HttpContent;
        ResponseText: Text;
        IsSucces: Boolean;
        Item_Vendor_Catalog: Report "Item/Vendor Catalog";
        ItemVendor: Record "Item Vendor";
        Json1: JsonObject;
        out: OutStream;
        ins: InStream;
        RecRef: RecordRef;
        TempBlob_lRec: Codeunit "Temp Blob";
        FileManagement_lCdu: Codeunit "File Management";
        Base64: Codeunit "Base64 Convert";
    begin

        Headers := Client.DefaultRequestHeaders();
        Headers.Add('Authorization', StrSubstNo('Bearer %1', AccessToken));
        Headers.Add('Accept', 'application/json;odata=nometadata');

        ItemVendor.Get(Item."Vendor No.", Item."No.");
        Item_Vendor_Catalog.SetTableView(ItemVendor);

        RequestMessage.SetRequestUri(Url);
        RequestMessage.Method('POST');

        TempBlob_lRec.CreateOutStream(out, TEXTENCODING::UTF8);
        RecRef.Get(ItemVendor.RecordId);
        Report.SaveAs(Report::"Item/Vendor Catalog", '', ReportFormat::Pdf, out);
        TempBlob_lRec.CreateInStream(ins, TEXTENCODING::UTF8);
        // ins.Read(out);

        // Message(Base64.ToBase64(ins));
        // Message('out ' + Format(out));
        // Message('ins ' + Format(ins));
        System.CopyStream(out, ins);

        RequestContent.WriteFrom(ins);
        RequestMessage.Content(RequestContent);

        if Client.Send(RequestMessage, ResponseMessage) then
            if ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode() then begin
                if ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAs(ResponseText) then
                    IsSucces := true;
            end else
                ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAs(ResponseText);
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your report is actually getting generated.
I would add a variable `Parameters: Text` and make the following changes

```
Item_Vendor_Catalog.SetTableView(ItemVendor);
Parameters := Item_Vendor_Catalog.RunRequestPage();
...
Report.SaveAs(Report::"Item/Vendor Catalog", Parameters, ReportFormat::Pdf, out);
```

You can remove this line of code `RecRef.Get(ItemVendor.RecordId);` and I think it should work.